# I'm facing error in trigger(Encountered the symbol "IF" when expecting one of the following: ; <an identifier> <a double-quoted delimited-identifier>)

Tags: oracle, triggers, oracle-apex

--I am a beginner in oracle and facing an error while executing a trigger and need your help

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER hamza 
AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE ON RAW_MATERAIL
FOR EACH ROW 


DECLARE 
 VAR number;
BEGIN

SELECT COUNT(*) into VAR FROM ROW_STOCK WHERE MATERIAL_ID = :NEW.MATERIAL_ID ;

    IF nvl(VAR,0) = 0 THEN
        begin
            INSERT INTO RAW_STOCK
            (MATERIAL_ID, WEIGHT_OF_MATERIAL) values
            (:new.MATERIAL_ID, :new.WEIGHT);
            exception
            when dup_val_on_index then
            null;    
            end if;   
    ELSE VAR > 0 THEN
        begin
        UPDATE RAW_STOCK
        SET WEIGHT_OF_MATERIAL=  nvl(WEIGHT_OF_MATERIAL,0) + nvl(:NEW.WEIGHT,0) 
        WHERE MATERIAL_ID = :NEW.MATERIAL_ID ; 
        end if;   
END;
```

Answer (score 1):

Every `IF` has to have its `END IF`; the same goes for `BEGIN`, which has to have its `END`.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER hamza
   AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE
   ON RAW_MATERAIL
   FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
   VAR  NUMBER;
BEGIN
   SELECT COUNT (*)
     INTO VAR
     FROM ROW_STOCK
    WHERE MATERIAL_ID = :NEW.MATERIAL_ID;

   IF VAR = 0
   THEN
      BEGIN
         INSERT INTO RAW_STOCK (MATERIAL_ID, WEIGHT_OF_MATERIAL)
              VALUES (:new.MATERIAL_ID, :new.WEIGHT);
      EXCEPTION
         WHEN DUP_VAL_ON_INDEX
         THEN
            NULL;
      END;
   ELSIF VAR > 0
   THEN
      UPDATE RAW_STOCK
         SET WEIGHT_OF_MATERIAL =
                NVL (WEIGHT_OF_MATERIAL, 0) + NVL (:NEW.WEIGHT, 0)
       WHERE MATERIAL_ID = :NEW.MATERIAL_ID;
   END IF;
END;
```

Comment: now facing (: SQL Statement ignored Error at line 6: PL/SQL: ORA-00942: table or view does not exist) error after using this code

Comment: That means that table you're trying to access either doesn't exist or you don't have privilege to use it. Do you own that table? If so, is its name correctly spelled? If you don't own it, how did you acquire privileges on it? If it is via role, it won't work in named PL/SQL procedures (triggers included) so you'll have to grant privileges directly to user.

Comment: Is RAW_MATERAIL correct? Shouldn't that be RAW_MATERIAL?

Comment: Thank u now its almost working but insertion part works properly but updating portion is not working

Comment: What does it mean "is not working"? I can't test it, I don't have your tables nor data.

Comment: I understand that u have not my tables but I want to say that whenever I enter a new row in the raw_material table it also inserts in the raw_stock table but I want to update the weight of existing product present in row if u can understand te situation and can help me i will be thankful to u otherwise no problem :)

Comment: UPDATE looks OK. Debug the trigger - include calls to DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE and display various values trigger is working with so that you'd see what's really going on.